# selenium problem- .wep files doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i was trying to make automatic scrapping program for practice.
This program works for this:

- The user enters a search term
- Search for a search term that corresponds to YouTube
- Capture all the thumbnails of the 10 videos attached to the top
- Scrape the past including YouTuber name, video title, upload, view count, and preview content
- Save the thumbnail file to movies/search word name/thumbnail
- Save the title, YouTuber, upload date, number of views, and preview contents in movies/search term name/INFO
- Please upload little by little to the concatenated file in the order of thumbnail / YouTuber name / upload date / title / preview / number of views.
- If the title is a special character, write the special character as the memo title

The point is i was trying to save images in excel file too.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import ssl
import time 
from PIL import Image

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

def safe_create_directory(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

def sanitize_filename(filename):
    s = re.sub(r'[\\/*?:"<>|]', "", filename)
    return s.strip()

# Initialize
search_query = input("검색어를 입력하세요: ")
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Wait for loading
time.sleep(5)

# Open YouTube and input search query
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

# Wait for loading
time.sleep(5)

search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "search_query")))
search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys(search_query)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for loading
time.sleep(5)

# Scroll to load more videos
scroll_pause_time = 2
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
target_video_count = 20

video_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-video-renderer")
data = []

while len(data) < target_video_count:
    video_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-video-renderer")
    
    if not video_elements:
        # Scroll to load more videos
        print("썸네일 못가져와서 스크롤합니다")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "continuations")))
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
        continue

for video in video_elements:
    title = video.find_element(By.ID, "video-title").text
    sanitized_title = sanitize_filename(title)
    
    # 업로더 정보 추출
    try:
        uploader_element = video.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string")
        uploader = uploader_element.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        uploader = "Unknown Uploader"
    
    views = video.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.style-scope.ytd-video-meta-block")[0].text
    
    # 썸네일 이미지 요소 찾기
    try:
        thumbnail_img_element = video.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yt-image img")
        thumbnail_src = thumbnail_img_element.get_attribute("src")
        
        if thumbnail_src:
            # 썸네일 저장
            thumbnail_folder = f"movies/{search_query}/Thumbnail/"
            safe_create_directory(thumbnail_folder)
            thumbnail_path = f"{thumbnail_folder}{sanitized_title}.jpg"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(thumbnail_src, thumbnail_path)
            
            # 데이터 리스트에 저장하여 나중에 엑셀로 내보내기 위함
            image_filename = f"{sanitized_title}.jpg"
            data.append([title, uploader, views, image_filename])
            print(f"('{title}'의 '{image_filename}/{sanitized_title}/{uploader}/{views}' )저장했습니다")
        else:
            print(f"('{title}'의 썸네일을 못 가져왔습니다)")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f"('{title}'의 썸네일을 못 가져왔습니다)")
        
        # Save thumbnail
        thumbnail_folder = f"movies/{search_query}/Thumbnail/"
        safe_create_directory(thumbnail_folder)
        thumbnail_path = f"{thumbnail_folder}{sanitized_title}.jpg"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(thumbnail_src, thumbnail_path)
        
        # Save info to a list for later excel export
        image_filename = f"{sanitized_title}.jpg"
        data.append([title, uploader, views, image_filename])
        print(f"('{title}'의 '{image_filename}/{sanitized_title}/{uploader}/{views}' )저장했습니다")

    # Scroll to load more videos
    print("스크롤합니다")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "continuations")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

# Save info to text file
info_folder = f"movies/{search_query}/INFO/"
safe_create_directory(info_folder)
info_file_path = f"{info_folder}{search_query}.txt"
with open(info_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as info_file:
    for item in data:
        info_file.write(f"Title: {item[0]}\n")
        info_file.write(f"Uploader: {item[1]}\n")
        info_file.write(f"Views: {item[2]}\n")
        info_file.write(f"Image Filename: {item[3]}\n\n")

# Save to Excel
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Title", "Uploader", "Views", "Image Filename"])

# Save to Excel with images
excel_folder = f"movies/{search_query}_excel/"
safe_create_directory(excel_folder)
excel_path = f"{excel_folder}{search_query}.xlsx"

# Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(workbook, index=False, sheet_name='Videos')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = workbook.book
worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('Videos')

# Get the dimensions of the DataFrame
max_row = df.shape[0]
max_col = df.shape[1]

# Add the image column
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)  # Adjust the width of the image column

# Add images to the Excel file
for row_num in range(1, max_row + 1):
    image_path = df.loc[row_num - 1, 'Image Filename']
    img_path = f"movies/{search_query}/Thumbnail/{image_path}"
    worksheet.insert_image(row_num, max_col, img_path, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})  # Adjust the scale

workbook.close()

print(f"All data saved. Excel file path: {excel_path}")

# Close browser
driver.quit()
```

This is my code.
It opens Chrome browser well and enters correct keyword which i typed.
The problem is, nothing happens after that.
I even tried to wait for 10 minutes but it didn't worked.

First i thought it was SSL problem and i searched for answer.
I put these code but it didn't helped

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Before I updated code,  It worked. but when i tried to save thumbnails , wep file made problems too.

I wanna know how to save wep files and conflict this problem.

Thanks for reading